# Regex Need to Match word but exclude other words in any order

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following combination of lines:-

```
WAN-bridge
bridge-WAN
WAN-VLAN
ether1-WAN        <-----
ether2-hello
ether2-wan2        <-----
WAN-BRIDGE
wan-bridge
bridge-wan
vlan918-WAN
VLAN-wan
wan-ether1        <-----
wan-Bridge
```

I need a `PCRE` regex to match any line that contains `'wan'` but excludes the words `'vlan'` and 'bridge' in any order and irrespective of case.

I have marked the lines I wish to match.

I have tried so many variations, but none have worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, and what did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
^(?=.*wan)(?!.*(vlan|bridge)).*$
```

- `^` - start of string.
- `(?=.*wan)` - positive lookahead. condition for `wan` must be in line.
- `(?!.*(vlan|bridge))` - negative lookahead. condition for `vlan and bridge` must not be in line.
- `.*` - match anything except new line.
- `$` - end of string.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/CR5o6y/1/)